# Test scripts for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, patch

i am new in the SharePoint worlds and I am asked to create a list of items (document libraries , lists , etc... ) that needs to be checked every time security patches are installed ? later,I will be creating a script to see if something went wrong during the installation.

Thanks

Comment: What is this list going to contain? Are you saying you need to check the contents of the list after updating SharePoint?  Your question is very vague.

Comment: this list should contain all the SharePoint components that need to be checked

Comment: such as libraries , lists , site pages , etc...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.